# Windows 7 shows only current wireless network in "manage wireless networks"

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

my Windows 7 shows only the current connected wireless network in "manage wireless networks". Because of that I'm not able to remove other networks, which I won't use anymore.

I'm sure that there are other stored networks because I'm working in another city and it's connecting in both towns without asking for the passwords.

Is there an option, which I could have set accidently? Is there another way to manage the wireless networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our company's admin installed **Intel PROSet/Wifi Connection Utility** on all laptops. Network settings are stored by that utility, and won't appear in "manage wireless networks". I didn't noticed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "add" (one of the tabs in the manage wireless networks section) and choose a wireless network to add. If you want to delete a network, but it is not showing up, it is already deleted, however there is no real way to permanently delete a network.

Comment: I definitely don't want to "add" something. As I said, I use two different password protected networks, but I can only see the one, I'm connected with. I don't have to reenter the passwords every time, so it must be stored.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.  It turns out that if the Adapter manufacture software is managing the Wifi adapter, Windows does not store profile info.  I launched the Intel Wifi Connection Utility and chose to let Windows manage the adapter and the problem was resolved.

Good luck!